# Cypress: Why finicky in handling spec's after hook?

Tags: cypress, hook, cypress-after-hook

Blocked by a Cypress custom command not executing properly within a **spec's after hook** when a test failed. Experimented with the following minimal spec examples.

**Context**

Testing two Cypress custom commands:

- `cy.cmdLogin()`: Standard username password authentication
- `cy.cmdLogout()`: `cy.get('logout_button').click()`

**Spec #1, `cy.cmdLogout()` in after hook does work**

Very simple Cypress tests spec, test `cy.cmdLogin()` with after hook with `cy.cmdLogout()`, works perfectly:

```
 context('SPEC Login', () => {
    after('AFTER Logout', () => {
      if (this.successLogin) {
        cy.cmdLogout().then(() => {
          cy.log('Logout Success');
        });
      }
    });

    it('TEST Login', () => {
      cy.cmdLogin().then(() => {
        cy.log('Login Success');
        this.successLogin = true;
      });
    });
  });
```

**Spec #2, `cy.cmdLogout()` in after hook does not work**

Modified Cypress tests spec, test `cy.cmdLogin()` with after hook with `cy.cmdLogout()`, now added a test that forced failure `expect(false).to.be.a('boolean').to.be.true;`. The after hook `cy.cmdLogout()` is called and fails:

Verified that Cypress could handle `cy.get('logout_button')` without failure.

Yet, extending with `.click()`, `cy.get('logout_button').click()`, Cypress would throw an error: Can not perform `click()` on `undefined`.

```
 context('SPEC Login', () => {
    after('AFTER Logout', () => {
      if (this.successLogin) {
        cy.cmdLogout().then(() => {
          cy.log('Logout Success');
        });
      }
    });

    it('TEST Login', () => {
      cy.cmdLogin().then(() => {
        cy.log('Login Success');
        this.successLogin = true;
      });
    });

    it('TEST Fail', () => {
      expect(false).to.be.a('boolean').to.be.true;
    });
  });
```

**Spec #3, removed after hook, `cy.cmdLogout()` moved to another test does work**

Modified Cypress tests spec again and removed after hook, test `cy.cmdLogin()`, test forced failure, and now test `cy.cmdLogout()`. This works perfectly:

```
  context('SPEC Login', () => {
    it('TEST Login', () => {
      cy.cmdLogin().then(() => {
        cy.log('Login Success');
        this.successLogin = true;
      });
    });

    it('TEST Fail', () => {
      expect(false).to.be.a('boolean').to.be.true;
    });

    it('TEST Logout', () => {
      if (this.successLogin) {
        cy.cmdLogout().then(()=> {
          cy.task('log', 'Logout Success');
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

**Insight as to why Cypress is finicky with spec's after hook would be very much appreciated**

Comment: [Sessions, local storage, cookies, etc, are cleared before each test](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Is-resetting-the-state-necessary). Your `after()` may not be necessary.

Comment: Please see warning at [Best Practices - Using after or afterEach hooks](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Using-after-or-afterEach-hooks)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer (for the general situation) is change `after()` hook to `before()` hook, but in your case that wouldn't work because `this.successLogin` will always be undefined inside a `before`.

You would need to create a `cy.isLoggedIn()` command or call `cy.cmdLogout()` unconditionally.

To get `after()` the logic working on a fail, use

```js
after('AFTER Logout', () => {
  cy.cmdLogout()
});

Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
  cy.cmdLogout()
  throw error 
})
```

which is equivalent to this in plain javascript

```js
try {
  some-code-that-might-error()
  cy.cmdLogout()                // does not run if error occurs
} catch (error) {
  cy.cmdLogout()                // do the logout in error situation
}
```